# iOS - Can saving to Library/Caches/ result in error?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

If an app starts saving virtually unlimited images (on demand) to the /Library/Caches directory for caching purpose, what will happen when the storage is full? **Will saving to the caches folder result in error?** OR **If the app is open, can the cache of the open app be purged by iOS automatically?** If not, **is it the responsibility of the developer to initiate this purging process for the open app?** OR **Is it guaranteed that an attempt to save an image to /Library/Caches will always be successful regardless of whether the purging takes place or not?** (Cached images are cleaned by the app on exit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it may result in error. No, it will not be purged by iOS automatically while an app is running. Quote from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html):

**Caches**

> On iOS 5.0 and later, the system may delete the Caches directory on rare occasions when the system is very low on disk space. This will never occur while an app is running

So it's your responsibility to cleanup the caches directory while running. However you would probably meet this error in a very rare cases since iOS will try to remove caches of other apps that are not running.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out @Sega-Zero, is it possible to know whether there is enough space in the Cache to save another image? OR Is it possible to detect that Purging is required?

Comment: Well, you may try two ways: 
1. try to write to disk, check for error if any (pretty bad way, but safe enough)
2. check available free space and compare to saving block size. this may be done via very simple code like this:
    `NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *dir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    NSDictionary *attrs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:dir error:&error];
    if ([[attrs valueForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize] unsignedLongLongValue] < picSize) save();`